# how do i go about using a bubble sort for sorting 4 arrays from least to greatest? c++

Tags: c++

i have 4 arrays which are parallel to each other. one of the arrays holds an integer value. I'm supposed to make the array that holds the integer value sorted from smallest integer value to greatest integer value. The part I'm confused about is after i use the bubble sort technique is that my other 3 arrays that were parallel to the integer array are no longer parallel because the subscript value changed. How do I go about making my other 3 arrays parallel to the new integer array values. Say that I have IntegerArray[0]=2 IntegerArray[1]=1 and I then sort it in order IntegerArray[0]=1 IntegerArray[1]=2 how would I make sure that my other arrays are parallel? say that IntegerArray[0]=2 (the original before sorting) was parallel with say NameArray[0]=Greg NameArray[1]=George if I ran a for loop to print my array values how would I make it so that names array would be parallel with my sorted integer array? Also besides the name array, I have two other arrays that need to be parallel as well.

Comment: Is this use of "parallel" your invention? I have never heard it before. And you claim that you start with `{2, 2}` and sort it to get `{1, 2}`, which indicates that you are not proofreading. Finally, I suggest that you try a simpler problem: sorting one array while making the same swaps in another: `{Carol, Alice, Bob}+{1, 2, 3} => {Alice, Bob, Carol}+{3, 1, 2}`. Then try reordering an array according to an index array: `{Alice, Bob, Carol}+{3, 1, 2} => {Carol, Alice, Bob}`. After that, the rest should be obvious.

Comment: sorry about that. I meant IntegerArray[1]=1 I edited it.

Comment: The solution is to use an array of structures instead of many parallel arrays.

Comment: @cobra916 Don't sort the arrays, sort an array of indices instead.  If you had 10 parallel arrays instead of 3, would you really try and sort each and every one?

Comment: @Beta "parallel arrays" are a thing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array

Comment: share your code here.

Comment: @user2079303: News to me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting 4 parallel arrays can be implemented in exactly the same way as a sorting a single array, except in the part where you would swap two values of the single array, you instead swap the corresponding indices in all 4 of the arrays.

Another approach is to "zip" the arrays into a single array of class objects and sort that. This allows you to use a regular sorting algorithm with no changes to swapping, but of course requires zipping and unzipping of the parallel arrays.

Answer (score 0):

One way to sort parallel arrays is to not sort the arrays themselves, but sort an array of index values that point to the first, second, third, etc. item into the arrays.

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string names[5] = { "Jack", "Joe", "Alice", "Bob", "Carol" };
    int grades[5] = { 80, 75, 90, 95, 68 };
    //...
    int index[5] = { 0,1,2,3,4 };
    //...
    // perform bubble sort on the grades in ascending order
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
            if (grades[index[j]] > grades[index[j+1]])
                std::swap(index[j], index[j+1]);
    }

    // print out the sorted values, sorted by grade in ascending order
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        std::cout << names[index[i]] << " " << grades[index[i]] << "\n";
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/2IaMm1)

Note that the only thing actually swapped are values in the array of indices.  The arrays with the actual data are never changed.

Comment: well I think I figured it out for my homework assignment. I'm getting the correct output so far. I'm confused why for some bubble sorts they'll use a code like (K = 0; K <= count - 2; K++) where your count is the total number of indices compared to (K = 0; K <= count - 1; K++) why is it that some code uses a subtract 1 and some subtract 2?